# How to know whether the user redirected (or coming) from facebook or WhatsApp or any other website in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel, tracking

how to know whether the user redirected (or coming) from facebook or WhatsApp or Gmail or any other website.

Comment: If available: [`$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) contains the URL the user is coming from

Answer (score 0):

You can check the referer using this function:

```
Request::server('HTTP_REFERER')
```

But not all user agents will set this http parameter so you can find a null value returned.

Answer (score 0):

You can use php superglobal variable `$_SERVER`. 
Following will work for you.

```
 if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])) {
      echo $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
  }
```